# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, onclick, syntax-error, tofixed

I know that others have had this error thrown but I think I have some sort of syntax problem that's causing this to happen for me. If you can find it I would be grateful. I'm new to JavaScript and have been staring at this simple program for an hour.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var calculateFV = function(investmentAmount, interestRate, yearsAmount) {
    var futureValue;

    //get the future value after the amount of years entered
    for (var i = 1; i <= yearsAmount; i++ ) {
        var interest = futureValue * interestRate / 100;
        futureValue = futureValue + interest;
    }

    return futureValue.toFixed(2);
};

var processEntries = function(investmentAmount, interestRate, yearsAmount) {
    var investment = investmentAmount;
    var interest = interestRate;
    var years = yearsAmount;

    var futureValue = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
    $("calculate").value = futureValue;
};

window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;  
};
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="future_value.css">
 <script src="future_value.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <main>
     <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>

     <label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
     <input type="text" id="investment"><br>

     <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
     <input type="text" id="rate">%<br>

     <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
     <input type="text" id="years"><br>

     <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
     <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>

     <label>&nbsp;</label>
     <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>      
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Nvm, you're not doing jQuery.  In any case, the issue with the onclick only passing in the event remains the primary issue

Comment: `futureValue` will be `undefined` if `yearsAmount` if less than or equal `1` because of the `for` loop

Comment: Does it help initializing futureValue like so `var futureValue = 0;`?

Comment: @Taplar , can you please explain what you mean? I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: When you assign an event handler (ex. `someElement.onclick = function`), the main thing that is passed into the method when the event happens is the event object.  Not any other expected parameters you put on the callback.  The first parameter will be the event.  If you want to pass other things in, you either have to call the method yourself with the arguments, or use `bind()` to change what is passed in by default

Comment: @glitch I tried that but no...

Comment: looks like either futureValue or interest resulted in Undefined, to ensure that this does not return Undefined, i would replace the line with futureValue.toFixed(2); with let a = futureValue ? futureValue : 0; a.toFixed(2);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`futureValue` is only given a value in the event that the `i <= yearsAmount` loop executes at least once. However, it isn't executing even once: this is because `yearsAmount` will always be undefined. Why? Let's take a look at how this function gets called:

```
var futureValue = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
```

This is where `calculateFV` is called, so `years` must be undefined. `years` is just the parameter `yearsAmount` from your `processEntries` header:

```
var processEntries = function(investmentAmount, interestRate, yearsAmount) {
```

So we know `processEntries` got called with an undefined third argument.

This line is the culprit:

```
$("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
```

An element's `onclick` event only gets called with *one* argument: the event object. The code doesn't know you want it to pass the values of the input boxes labeled `investment`, `interest`, and `years`. So, instead of three numbers, you get one event object and two `undefined` values. Instead you need to select these elements and get their values in `processEntries` yourself.

That would look something like this:

```
var processEntries = function(event) { //notice only the event will be given
    //text box values will be strings, so convert to number with Number()
    var investment = Number($("investment").value);
    var interest = Number($("rate").value);
    var years = Number($("years").value);

    var futureValue = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
    $("calculate").value = futureValue;
};
```

Comment: AH, I just realized that you're right I never got the values from the text boxes. I'm sure that'll help me fix it, thank you!

Comment: there's no error anymore, thanks so much for the great explanation!

Answer (score 9):

In some cases when we bind the data directly in html, there is a chances like it may take sometime to load, so we may get the above error.

In my case I used **"?"** operator

**for ex:- customer.price?.toFixed(2)**

Comment: straight to the point working solution

Answer (score 5):

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined**

Following code to fix the above error.

```
var test = 12.520;
console.log(Number(test).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the `processEntries()` arguments from another way. This way the only argument you gonna receive directly is the event object. Inside the `processEntries` function, try to do something like this instead:

```js
var processEntries = function() {
    var investment = $('investment').value;
    var interest = $('rate').value;
    var years = $('years').value;

    var futureValue = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
    $("calculate").value = futureValue;
};
```

Probably you will need to format the texts correctly after you grabbing the values, try to `consol.log` them before calling the last function for debug purposes.